# Polymer retrieving list from Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, polymer

I need to pass in a list from Flask to Polymer object. What is the best way to achieve this? I cannot find a list property type in the Polymer documentation.

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'create-account',
        properties: {
            actionUrl: String,
            // organizations: I want a list here of names 
        }
    });

    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
    }
</script>
```

accountcreation.html

```
<body>
    <h1>Account Creation</h1>
    <create-account action-url={{ formControllerUrl }}
                        organizations={{ organizations }}></create-account>
</body>
```

Flask function

```
@home_bp.route('/create_account')
def create_account():
    import pdb
    organizations = Organization.query.with_entities(Organization.name).all()
    lst = []
    for o in organizations:
        lst.append(o[0])
    pdb.set_trace()
    return render_template('accountcreation.html', 
            formControllerUrl=url_for('form.create_account'), organzations=lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with quotations used in Json. I should pass in `organizations` as such `'{"hello", "world"}'`. Instead, this was getting passed in as `"{"hello", "world"}"`. Therefore, I simply modified `accountcreation.html` as such:

```
<body>
    <h1>Account Creation</h1>
    <create-account action-url={{ formControllerUrl }}
                        organizations='{{ organizations|tojson }}'></create-account>
</body>
```

Note, the single quotes surrounding `{{ organizations|tojson }}`.